# C the output of `harga` after `kartu_member_kode_diskon` = Rp 0.00 where did i do wrong?? + revise this code please

Tags: c, algorithm, function, math

im trying to make hotel reservations online program on c but i encounter a few problem like the price(`harga`) is equal to zero. i know i should've used file instead on `pilih_kamar_pojok_atau_engga1` but im too near to my deadlines

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void pesen_breakfast() {
    int harga_breakfast, breakfast, x;

    do {
        printf("Mau beli breakfast?\n1. Yes\n2. No\nPilih : ");
        scanf("%d", &breakfast);

        if (breakfast == 1) {
                printf("Berapa breakfast yang mau dibeli?\n");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                harga_breakfast = x * 150000;
                printf("Total yang harus dibayar : %d\n", harga_breakfast);
                final();
        } else if (breakfast == 2) {
            printf("Oke gausah beli breakfast\n"); //ganti apapun
            final();
        }
    } while (breakfast != 1 && breakfast != 2);

}

void final()
{
    int breakfast, harga_final, balik_menu;
    harga_final = harga_breakfast + harga;
    printf("Total harga: %f", harga_final);
    printf("Silahkan membayar di tempat saat ingin check-in\n");
    printf("Pembayaran juga dapat dilakukan melalui e-banking mana saja\n");
    printf("Terima kasih atas pembeliannya!\n");
    balikmenu();
}

void balikmenu() {
    int balik_menu;

    do {
        printf("Balik ke menu awal?\n1. Yes\n2. No\nPilih : ");
        scanf("%d", &balik_menu);

        if (balik_menu == 1) {
            // disini coding untu balik ke menu awal
            printf("Anda memilih: Yes\n");
        } else if (balik_menu == 2) {
            printf("Anda memilih: No\n");
        } else {
            printf("Pilihan yang anda masukkan salah\n");
        }

    } while (balik_menu != 2);

}
```

Im trying to make a hotel reservation app on c, this is a project but the price ( `harga` ) always go to zero. why did that happen??

Comment: Two of your routines declare an `int harga` that hides the previous definition, and they use the new `harga` without initializing it. Also, the statements like `kamar == Kamar1;` do not do anything, because those are comparisons, not assignments. Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Comment: Hello i have solve the price (`harga`) thing, but i have a new problem when the final price(`harga_final`) it didnt print the previous price(`harga`) + `breakfast` but only count the breakfast. why did this happen??

Comment: Are you this person? https://stackoverflow.com/users/23019904/michael-elbert-justian-0000009